# Probability question fair die roll

Tags: statistics

A fair die is rolled three times. What is the probability that the sequence of rolls is 1,2,3?

I just don't understand how to go about this problem at all, it confuses me. Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: you want to determine P(1st roll is 1) AND P(2nd roll is 2) AND P(3rd roll is 3). Have you been introduced to simple probability concepts before?

Comment: Yes, I just totally forgot how to do these problems. I remember now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: the hint by drhab will provide you with the answer, assuming you know each individual probability

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are three events that are independent then: $$P(A \text{ and }  B \text{ and }C)=P(A)\times P(B)\times P(C)$$

Here $A$ can be taken the event that the first roll gives $1$, $B$ the event that the second roll gives ...

et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions:

- Your die has six sides.  (Usually the problem will specify if the die has something other than six sides.)
- The die is "fair" if each number is equally likely to show up on a roll.

There are six possible outcomes $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.  The probability of getting any one of these particular numbers is $1/6$.  (All of the probabilities must add up to $1$, and since there are $6$ equally likely outcomes, the probability of each is $1/6$.)

So the probability of getting $1$ on the first roll is $1/6$.

How many possibilities are there if we roll the die again?  The first roll can show up $1,2,3,4,5,6$, and the second roll can show up $1,2,3,4,5,6$.  This makes $6 \times 6 = 36$ possible outcomes, each with probability $1/36$.  So the probability of getting a $1$ on the first roll and a $2$ on the second roll is $1/36$.

Use the same reasoning for three rolls.  (Answer: $1/216$)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now. Thank you for taking the time to explain it:)